# How do I use loop (for)

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, qcc

I'd like to use loop function in R with following code:

```
pc01 <- qcc(matrix(cbind(dta02[1:length(dta02)-1], dta02[2:length(dta02)]), ncol = 2), type = "R")
pc02 <- qcc(matrix(cbind(dta02[1:length(dta02)-1], dta02[2:length(dta02)]), ncol = 2), type = "R")
pc03 <- qcc(matrix(cbind(dta03[1:length(dta03)-1], dta03[2:length(dta03)]), ncol = 2), type = "R")
```

In order to make it easily, I used the 'function'

```
myqccF <- function(n)
{
 qcc(matrix(cbind(n[1:length(n)-1], n[2:length(n)]), ncol = 2), type = "R")
}
```

and then, how do I make the loop using the function 'myqccF' like the following code?

```
qc01 <- myqccF(dta01)
qc02 <- myqccF(dta02)
qc03 <- myqccF(dta03)
```

Comment: you can use assign function in the for-loop with paste0. Maybe like this:
for (i in 1:3){
  temp <- paste0("dta0",i)
  assign(paste0("qcc0",i), myqccF(temp))
}
but you might need to add 'return' function at the end of your function defining.

Answer (score 0):

You still have a loop, now it's a loop with your function in it.

```
for (i in 1:3) assign(paste0("qc0", i), myqccF(get(paste0("qc0", i))))
```